# Optimization problem of two variable

Tags: integration, functions, optimization, area

Find two numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a \leq b$ such that $\int_a^b (6-x-x^2)dx$ has the largest value.

Comment: The integrand is only positive between $-3$ and $2$. So $a=-3$ and $b=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $F(a,b) = 6(b-a) - \dfrac{b^2-a^2}{2}-\dfrac{b^3-a^3}{3} \to F_a = 6+a+a^2 = 0 = F_b = 6-b-b^2 \to a, b = 2,-3$. Can you continue...?

Comment: So, i have found a = 2,-3 , b = 3,-2. This means that i have 4 points (2,3) , (2,-2) , (-3,3) , (-3,-2) ? (Second is not valid a > b). Now i have to compute value on those points and make conclusion ?

Comment: True. You have $(a,b) = (2,3), (-3,3),(-3,-2)$, and you just evaluate the value of $F$ at these points and pick the largest.

Answer (score 0):

First perform the integration to have

$$ \Big[ 6x - \frac{1}{2} x^2 - \frac{1}{3} x^3 \Big]^b_a $$

which you can write into the form of

$$ (b-a) \Big[ 6 - \frac{1}{2} (b+a) - \frac{1}{3} (b^2+ab+a^2) \Big] = max $$

You can find the extrema using the standard techniques.